# Controll Flutter app audio from Android auto

Tags: android, flutter, android-auto, just-audio, audio-service

I'm working on an Audio Book app that need to be controlled from Android Auto and CarPlay. My app successfully worked with CarPlay. But I can't get it to work with android auto. I'm using `just_audio` with `just_audio_background` and Also using `audio_service`.

I saw some guy acctualy made it work with Android auto, but for some reason I can't. Here's my approch for playing the audio.

```
 AudioSource audioSource = AudioSource.uri(Uri.file(tmpFile),
            tag: MediaItem(
              id: state.audioBookModel?.partitionKey ?? '12',
              title: state.audioBookModel?.mainTitle ?? 'Audio Book',
              artist: state.audioBookModel?.author ?? 'writer',
              artUri: Uri.parse(
                  'https://arturi.com'),
              playable: true,
              duration: Duration(seconds: state.audioBookModel?.totalDurationInSeconds ?? 0)
            ));
 await audioPlayer?.setAudioSource(
         audioSource,
       );
 await audioPlayer?.play();
```

I also tested my app by uploading it to Internal Testing, and it gives me same result. It play the audio from the app but I can't controll it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to solve it by using `audio_session` Package.

In my main.dart I initialized the `AudioSession` like this.

```
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration.music());
```

Also I added this meta-data Into my Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
    android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
```

automotive_app_desc.xml is located in res/xml folder

```
<automotiveApp>
   <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>
```